# SUM multiple columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, aggregate-functions

so I have a problem trying to sum up all column values.
I need to sum up 4 column values in order to echo the total. Column values can only be 1 or 0. 
Here's the code:

```
$q = $mysqli->query("SELECT SUM(0_title + 1_title + 2_title + 3_title + 4_title + 5_title) AS total from PlayerTitles");
$row1 = $q->fetch_assoc();
echo $row1['SUM(total)'];
```

And it does not display anything. I just need a total amount of titles. Please help, thank you.

Comment: Stop. See normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used "AS total" in the query so that will be the array index:

```
$row1['total']
```

Comment: I missed the obvious, the SUM() is not needed: SELECT 0_title + 1_title...etc